# Low-pass filter on subset of data

Tags: r, fourier-transform, filter

I have a time series with 15-minute sampling frequency. When the data is greater than 0, there is a lot of noise, but when the data is less than 0, there is very little noise. I am trying to find a way to apply a low-pass filter (in R) to this data so that it removes the noise when the data is greater than 0. I have been experimenting with the "signal" package and also "spectrum" in base. I've managed to get it to work a bit on the entire signal using a Butterworth filter, but that is a phase-shifting filter...I want a zero-phase shift filter.

I am having trouble (I think) with how exactly to approach this problem. Basically, I have tried to view the spectrum of the entire signal and also of the signal subset (i.e., >0), but it's so noisy, and plotted on a log(y)-axis, that it's hard to determine what a cutoff frequency should be.

I want to just simply and quickly be able to plot the filtered time-series against the original so that I can determine if the filter is appropriate, but right now this is slow and laborious. Suggestions?

Thank you!